# Both start debugging and running in non-debug mode will stop at the breakpoint in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When I use vscode to run my c++ program, I found both start debugging and run in non-debug mode will stop at the breakpoint. Why does this happen? How can I run the program without stopping at the breakpoint?

Comment: Execute your application binary from the command line.

Comment: When you run in "non-debug mode", how do you run your program? What is the VSCode configuration for that? And when you say it "stop at the break point", does it stop in the debugger? If not then what really happens?

Comment: I clicked the start debugging (F5) and non-debugging mode (ctrl F5) tabs under the run tab to run. The configuration file is automatically generated. In both modes, it stopped at the breakpoint and entered debug mode. But I think the correct one is the debug mode and the one that runs directly.

Comment: And you're sure there's no crash that just happens to be where the breakpoint is set?

Comment: No crash. In both situations, I can continue stepping